# Where is the auto award for bounties for Space.SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator, bounty, reputation

I have lost around 800 reputation over time on Space.SE in lost bounties because I missed the dead-line to award it. I think the bulk of it may have been lost during a suspension, does that effect bounties?

[How does the speed and volume of particles differ in producing thrust in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33025/how-does-the-speed-and-volume-of-particles-differ-in-producing-thrust-in-space)

It had a 500 rep bounty placed on 09-Feb-2019 and no one got it.

[image]

Side question: I read somewhere on SE, more features were given to moderators a couple weeks ago.
Does the moderator have any control over bounties?

Comment: Check [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/303080) to see if your question is answered there. You "loose" reputation the moment you start the bounty. If you fail to award it to someone the way you would have liked to, then *they also loose* because you missed the dead-line.

Comment: @uhoh I updated the question.

Comment: okay, now check the link in my comment again, is there anything about this situation written there?

Comment: @uhoh nice. ...have a score of at least 2 (at the time the automatic awarding takes place), and

Comment: @uhoh I wish the bounties would stay until an answer is given. I think I lost some there too.

Comment: ya, it's not a perfect system. There was a some scamming and gaming of the bounty system in the beginning, and a lot of the rigidity of the rules now are there to prevent that kind of activity. So it's not as flexible as we would like it to be.

Comment: @uhoh  I don't think having time extensions for unanswered questions would be asking for too much?

Comment: Before you ask, do some reading in meta, and find out the reason that there is a time limit of 7 days, with 1 extra "grace period" day. I have a hunch that it has been discussed extensively and the reasons are pretty solid. After all these years, it's probably asking quite a lot to change it and test it, and make sure a large number of users want it changed.

Comment: Does the moderator have any control over that? I will read but exceptions have a purpose. Just make a smarter platform. I don't see anything really new or different really in the coding.

Comment: Almost every decision around the way these things work is for very good reasons - the sheer number of visitors (50 million a month across the SE network) means solutions need to work and be scalable. There have been various feature requests regarding bounties over the years, but the current model is pretty solid (despite inconveniences as Uhoh mentioned)

Comment: And no, mods have nothing to do with it - reading the faq on meta will give you all this info, and all the info uhoh provided is in there as well. Seriously - please read all the faq posts on meta.se

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'm not new but always learning new stuff. Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the bulk of it may have been lost during a suspension, does that effect bounties?

Checking [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/303080) we see that you "loose" the reputation the moment you start the bounty. If you fail to award it to someone the way you would have liked to for any reason, then they also lose it.

I also found that *you lose the auto-award* if you are suspended, or no one answers.

> ...have a score of at least 2 (at the time the automatic awarding takes place)...

While suspended, a user's reputation is (temporarily) set to exactly 1, definitively less than 2.

Comment: It's a little rough, but it seems to answer your question. If I get a chance is it okay if I polish the wording a little bit?

Comment: @uhoh they could help like you have on using comments as answers, but hey didn't Thank You so much!

Comment: @uhoh in the future I will use this format.

Comment: @uhoh why don't you try being a moderator?

Comment: It's quite a challenging job, you have to have an ocean of patience to do it well.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I like the ones here but you would make a good one too.

Comment: moderation is not my strong suit. I prefer to be a user so I can be myself.

Comment: Should be called Mentors

Comment: yes that is probably a much better description of what I would like to be, strictly peer-to-peer. But the only reason SE sites work so well is because of light touch yet firm and clear moderation.